Join between model and view in C# with EF Core
WorkflowData is a table in database
public class WorkflowData : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ... others properties
    public ICollection<WorkflowDataDynamicColumn> WorkflowDataDynamicColumns { get; set; }
}

WorkflowDataDynamicColumn is a view in my database.
public class WorkflowDataDynamicColumn
{
    public int WorkflowDataId { get; set; }
    public string? Value { get; set; }
}

I need to query the WorkflowData records and for each record get a key of that object a list of objects with the relationships in WorkflowDataDynamicColumn - how can I do that?
I tried with this code, but it does not work:
var query = _context.WorkflowDatas
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.WorkflowStatus)
                .Include(wd => wd.WorkflowDataDynamicColumns)
                .Where(x => x.WorkflowStatus != null)
                .Select(wd => new WorkflowDataDto
                              {
                                  Id = wd.Id,
                                  WorkflowStatus = wd.WorkflowStatus == null ? null : _mapper.Map<WorkflowStatusDto>(wd.WorkflowStatus),
                                  FormColumn = wd.WorkflowDataDynamicColumns
                                                 .Select(dc => new WorkflowDataFormColumnDto
                                                               {
                                                                   Id = dc.Id,
                                                                   Value = dc.Value ?? string.Empty,
                                                               }).ToList()
                              })
                .ToListAsync();

Error message:

Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'WorkflowData.WorkflowDataDynamicColumns' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

This is the payload I need:
{
  "id": 21094,
  "workflowStatus": { ... }
  "formColumn": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "abc"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "value": "def"
    },
    ...
  ]
}

Context:
modelBuilder.Entity<WorkflowData>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(x => x.IsActive).HasDefaultValue(true);
                entity.HasMany(x => x.WorkflowDataDynamicColumns)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey(x => x.WorkflowDataId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<WorkflowDataDynamicColumn>()
                .HasNoKey()
                .ToView("vw_WorkflowDataDetails")
                .Property(x => x.WorkflowDataId).HasColumnName("WorkflowDataId");


Pretty much what the exception states. Set up the relationship. WorkflowDynamicDataColumn will need to nominate a Key to uniquely identify a row. From there either in the OnModelConfiguring or using an IEntityTypeConfiguration, set up the relationship between WorkflowData and this DataColumn. I.e. .HasMany(x => x.WorkflowDataDynamicColumns).WithOne().HasForeignKey(x => x.WorkflowDataid);

why is there sql-server in the tags ?

. Show your context code?

Use explicit join. There is no relationship between viaw and table. Since you are using Select it should be not a problem and your query do not need Includes at all.

@StevePy thanks, but not works.

@flackoverstow the context it is added in the question.

How can you reference a wc.Id to populate a form column ID when the entity is declared as modelBuilder.Entity<WorkflowDataDynamicColumn>().HasNoKey() and no reference to an Id in the class?  Please ensure you are including actual code, or an example that compiles and runs and demonstrates the issue. There are several issues with your code example. Your ToListAsync() call is not awaited, and I'm fairly sure that a _mapper.Map() call inside a projection (Select) will not run. A mechanic cannot diagnose a problem with a car when you bring a completely different vehicle into the shop.

You can't have a navigation to a keyless entity type.

Try to refactor your WorkflowDataDynamicColumn class as below.
public class WorkflowDataDynamicColumn
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Add primary Key
    public int WorkflowDataId { get; set; } 
    public virtual WorkflowData WorkflowData { get; set; } // Add foreign key relationship 
    public string? Value { get; set; }
}


Then it's still configured as keyless entity type.

The problem was that the view did not have a unique key.
"CREATE or ALTER VIEW WorkflowDataDynamicColumns AS
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY wd.Id) AS UniqueID,
wd.Id AS WorkflowDataId, ..."
